# User Configuration GPO doesn't apply to local users

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I've modified the Default Domain Policy GPO in a Server 2008 R2 installation and modified some User Configuration policies.

On the client machines, I've run `gpupdate /force` and logged in as a domain user.  I can see that the policies are applied fine.

When I log in as a local user (admin or non-admin), the user configuration policy isn't applied.

`rsop.msc` and `gpresult /R` show that no user configuration policies have been applied.

The scope of the default domain policy is Authenticated Users.

How can I make the user configuration policy apply to local users?

Comment: You...you can't. Group policy uses active directory, as in ...*domain* accounts.

Comment: As Nathan said...therefore you'd need to either copy the GP config files over locally or run gpedit locally and apply the same policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain based Group Policy does not apply to local users. Local Group Policy applies to local users. If the client OS is Windows Vista or newer you can use MLGPO to target local Group Policies to non-administrator users on the local machine. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766291(v=ws.10).aspx